# htaccess RewriteRule versioning number

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the css or js version number but I can't write a descent regex...

I have found some similar rewrite rule for htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]+\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L] # Strip out the version number
```

but I don't know how to change it for my sitation:

```
/assets/min/base_js.16.min.js
```

or

```
/assets/min/base_js.16.min.css
```

has to rewrite to:

```
/assets/min/base_js.min.css
```

Comment: You must be specific and give examples of names used formats

Answer (score 0):

You can use that in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.[\d]+\.((?:[^/.]+\.)?(?:css|js))$ $1.$2 [NC,L] # Strip out the version number
```